# Sorting shipping box sizes in excel smallest to largest

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a 500+ line spread sheet of box sizes and I need to sort them smallest box to largest box.

I have a helper column with:

```
=1*LEFT(D2,FIND(" ",D2)-1)
```

And another helper column with

```
+MID(D2,M2,FIND("X",D2,M2)-M2)
```

I don't know what to do with the last dimension and how do I get it to sort 1,2,3...10,11,12 and not 1,10,11,2,22,ect?

Here is a small sample of how the sizes are in the spread sheet.

```
5 X 5 X 10
5 X 5 X 3
5 X 5 X 4
6 X 4 X 3-1/2
6-3/4 X 6-3/4 X 12-1/8
6-3/4 X 6-3/4 X 7-3/4
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use one formula and drag it over three columns and then all three down the list:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($D1,"X",REPT(" ",999)),(COLUMN(A1)-1)*999+1,999)),"-"," ")
```

Starting from the inside:

`SUBSTITUTE($D1,"X",REPT(" ",999))` creates a string with large spaces between the three measurements.

`MID(...,(COLUMN(A1)-1)*999+1,999)` will pick a range of 999 characters along that string.  The first 999 in the first column, and so on as it is copied over.

`TRIM(...)` removes all the extra spaces.

`SUBSTITUTE(...,"-"," ")` Changes the `-` into spaces.  This is puts the fractions in a form that Excel can recognize.

`--` Turns the string to a number.

Now sort on the three columns in order.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a helper column with the Volume, then sort by that:

***Helper column formula** (Windows Excel 2013+):*

```
=PRODUCT(--SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","~")," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[not(contains(.,'X'))]"),"~"," "))
```

[image]